# Convert Xml hexadecimal values to integer in c#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, hex, type-conversion

I have the following xml:

```
<RootLevel>
  <Level1 type="Integer" value="0x53494553"/>
  <Level1 type="Float" value="0x07"/>
  <Level1 type="Short" value="0x0002"/>
  <Level1 type="Short" value="0x0000"/>
<RootLevel>
```

Respect to this xml, i get the Type value and cast them with no problem. But when i try to parse the hexadecimal values with

```
Convert.ToInt32(node.Attributes["value"].Value)
or
Convert.ToInt32(node.Attributes["value"].Value,NumberStyles.HexNumber)
or
int.Parse(node.Attributes["value"].Value)
or
int.Parse(node.Attributes["value"].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber)
```

It gives the following error:

Input string was not in a correct format.

In case i am trying to parse into integer but for every dataType it will be similar. Parsing for integer help is enough.

What am i missing here?

Comment: See also : http://theburningmonk.com/2010/02/converting-hex-to-int-in-csharp/

Comment: @PaulF Link is helpful and exactly what i was searching for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Converting Hex string to Int in C#**

For a hex literal that’s not prefixed you can quite easily convert it using int.Parse in C#:

```
string hex = "142CBD";
int intValue = int.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);    // this returns 1322173
```

But as you’ve probably noticed, most hex literals are prefixed with 0x (e.g. “0x142CBD”) which would throw a FormatException if you try to parse it using the above code.

In order to parse a 0x prefixed hex literal you need to use the Convert.ToInt32(string value, int fromBase) method instead:

```
string prefixedHex = "0x142CBD";
int intValue = Convert.ToInt32(prefixedHex , 16);     // this works, and returns 1322173
```

Comment: Probably int intValue = Convert.ToInt32(prefixedHex , 16);  is more accurate answer than mine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove start '0', 'x' chars. Try this:

```
if(int.TryParse(node.Attributes["value"].Value.Remove(0, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber)
{
     // your code
}
```